# Uniform convergence of a sum of integral functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions, uniform-convergence

I have to study punctual and uniform convergence of
$$g(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_n^{n+x}\dfrac{dt}{e^{t^3}}.$$
If I define $g_n(x)=\int_n^{n+x}\frac{dt}{e^{t^3}}$, in order to study the punctual convergence of $g(x)$, I have to compute $\lim_{n\to \infty}g_n$ with $x\in \mathbb R$ fixed. Since for $n\to \infty$, $n+x\sim n$ $\forall x\in \mathbb R$ I wrote
$$\int_n^{n+x}\dfrac{dt}{e^{t^3}}=\int_0^{n+x}\dfrac{dt}{e^{t^3}}-\int_0^{n}\dfrac{dt}{e^{t^3}}$$
which (I think) tends to zero and I'd say that the limit function of $g_n$ is the zero function, but I'm not sure about this. If I want to deduce the convergence of the series I should find a function asymptotic to $g_n$. The sum has form $\int_1^{1+x}\frac{dt}{e^{t^3}}+\int_2^{2+x}\frac{dt}{e^{t^3}}+\dots$, so how could I get informations about the convergence of the series? I don't understand how to do with the $n+x$ term because for $n<\infty$ it can assume any real value.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you know about $x$? Do you want to study convergence in whole $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @jojobo the only thing I know is $x\in \mathbb R$

Comment: Maybe you can compare it to $\frac{erf(x) \times \sqrt{\pi}}{2}$, but that gets complicated if $x$ is near $0$.

Answer (score 1):

It converges uniformly on any set $[a; +\infty)$, but doesn't converges uniformly on $\mathbb R$.

It's enough to check case $a < 0$. If $n > -a + 1$, $|g_n(x)| = \int\limits_{n + a}^n \frac{dt}{\exp(t^3)} < \int\limits_{n + a}^n e^{-t}\,dt < e^{-n - a}$. Taking $M_n = e^{-n - a}$ note that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty M_n$ converges, thus $\sum g_n(x)$ converges uniformly by Weierstrass M-test.

It doesn't converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$, because $g_n(-n - 1)$ doesn't even converges to $0$.

Comment: You need to check uniform convergence of $\sum_n g'_n(x)$ (and convergence of $\sum_n g_n(x)$).

Comment: Yes sorry I wanted to write it with the sum symbol before. How would you have studiied the punctual convergence of the series?

Comment: Pretty much the same way - explicitly find derivative and use M-test. $\exp((n + x)^3)$ goes to zero very fast after $n + x$ becomes positive (which happens after fixed number of terms if $x$ is bounded from below).

Comment: Yes, it should be $\sum g_n$, I forgot $\sum$ symbol too. I wrote that $\sum g_n$ doesn't converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$. It does converge on, say $[-1, \infty)$ - there is nothing special in $x = 0$ with this functions.

Comment: The exercise also asks me to calculate $\underset{x\to \lambda}{\lim}g(x)$, where $\lambda$ is the sup of the set of uniform convergence. In our case it  would be $+\infty$ right?